# Slow bash script for getting audio/video duration

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have created a bash script to generate a HTML file, which will have the duration of the audio/video files in the current folder. The script uses `ffprobe` to fetch the duration in the quiet mode and `file` to get the mime-type. Although, the script works as intended, **it feels a bit slow. I was wondering if it is possible to speed it up**. 
However, I don't have any experience in scripting and don't know about any time profiling tools. I did come across a stackoverflow answer on that topic, but time profiling can't suggest new libs or methods.

I did come across a suggestion on the SO from the python world using opencv and the benchmarks looked promising, but I am wary of installing such a huge library, and its big or small dependencies, just for this.

**EDIT**: By feeling slow I mean, I believe some of the commands I m using or the way I am using them have faster alternatives. On my one year old HDD, it is taking about a second to create the file for a mere 12 video files. Being a shell script, I was expecting C like speeds from this script or atleast from an optimized version of it.

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
file=$(printf "duration-${today}.html")
tot_dur=0
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
</style>
</head>
<body>" >> "${file}"
echo "<table>" >> "${file}"
echo "<tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
      </tr>" >> "${file}"
while read filename
do
    mime=$(file -b --mime-type "${filename}")
    IFS='/' read -r -a mime <<< "$mime"
    if [[ $mime == "video" || $mime == "audio" ]]; then
        duration=$(ffprobe -v quiet -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries format=duration "${filename}")
        tot_dur=$(echo $tot_dur + $duration | bc -l)
        duration=$(printf '%02d:%02d:%02f\n' $(echo -e "$duration/3600\n$duration%3600/60\n$duration%60"| bc | xargs echo))
        echo "<tr><td>"${filename}"</td><td>"${duration}"</td></tr>" >> "${file}"
    fi
done < <(ls)
# (find . -type f)
tot_dur=$(printf '%02d:%02d:%02f\n' $(echo -e "$tot_dur/3600\n$tot_dur%3600/60\n$tot_dur%60"| bc | xargs echo))
echo "<tr>
        <td><b>Total</td>
        <td><b>${tot_dur}</td>
      </tr>" >> "${file}"
echo "</table>" >> "${file}"
echo "</body> </html>" >> "${file}"
```

Just to be clear, I have already posted this question on code review, but didn't get any response. [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242115/slow-bash-script-for-getting-audio-video-duration)

Comment: Is the intention that this HTML file be created dynamically each time it's referenced? Will the files in the target directory change much? If not, it might be worth caching the result of `ffprobe` per file (for example, you could cache the timings for `Breakfast.mp4` in `Breakfast.ff`). At the start of each run, remove any `.ff` file that's older than the corresponding `.mp4` or for which there is no matching `.mp4`. Then iterate across the set of `.mp4` files, and create any `.ff` file that's missing. Finally, use all the `.ff` files to generate your HTML page.

Comment: good suggestion, so essentially you are saying that detecting the presence of `.ff` and reading the `.ff` will be much faster than the single operation of running `ffprobe` every time. Don't the video/audio contain that information in their header? Also, I might be wrong, but `ffprobe` developers might have optimized their code for that.

Comment: I don't see a precise question in your question. Can you get any closer than "it feels slow"? Is it performing fine but there's slowness across a network? Is it performing fine but-for some slow disks? Is it slow because it's inefficiently doing something? Said another way, you could speed it up by doing less work somehow, as roaima indicated.

Comment: ararg, it's difficult to provide absolute suggestions to a comment that "_it feels slow_". If you want precise answers you're going to need to provide precise data. For example, you could put timers in your code to identify what "slow" actually means (100ms? 1000ms? 10seconds?), where it's slow - perhaps it's the script itself, perhaps it's `ffprobe`, perhaps it's something entirely different.

Comment: `while read filename; do ... done < <(ls)` is (very) poor practice. Try `for filename in *; do ... done` instead

Comment: try concatenating consecutive echos ....

Comment: also try outputting all durations to a temporary file or variable and then add them up in bulk...

Comment: and try outsourcing everything that is not actually creating the table (like bulk html stuff) and concatenate the respective files afterwards.